# Could not find compatible version for activesupport (3.1.12)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, activesupport, bundle-install

I've got error with my `bundle install`.
In my Gemfile, i used

```
gem 'ar-octopus', :git => "git://github.com/tchandy/octopus.git", :require => "octopus"
```

but when i try to "`bundle install`"

it say:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    activesupport (3.1.12)

  In Gemfile:
    ar-octopus (>= 0) ruby depends on
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0) ruby

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

and I also do "`bundle update`", still with same error

Answer (score 0):

Your Rails version (3.1.12) is not compatible with `or-octopus` gem version you're trying to install (it requires Rails version to be 3.2 or higher).

Comment: so i need to upgrade my rails to version 3.2 ?

Comment: @agstwn21 yes, probably.